# Xamarin Forms Webview local

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, webview

Estoy intentando cargar una aplicación web (Readium) en un Webview con Xamarin.Forms de forma local. Como objetivo tengo UWP, Android e iOS.

No consigo que se abra la página index.html, he incrustado la Web en cada uno de los proyectos, según https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview/ pero me sale una página en blanco.

He implementado el servicio de dependencias para cada aplicación de la forma (UWP)

```
assembly: Dependency(typeof(BaseUrl))]
namespace WorkingWithWebview.UWP
{
    public class BaseUrl : IBaseUrl
    {
        public string Get()
        {
            return "ms-appx-web:///";
        }
    }
}
```

Sin embargo, creando un proyecto UWP nueva (sin Xamarin), sí que me funciona bien la carga de la aplicación, utilizando para ello el método NavigateToLocalStreamUri(uri, new StreamUriWinRTResolver()) con

```
public sealed class StreamUriWinRTResolver : IUriToStreamResolver
{
    public IAsyncOperation<IInputStream> UriToStreamAsync(Uri uri)
    {
        if (uri == null)
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }
        string path = uri.AbsolutePath; 
        return GetContent(path).AsAsyncOperation();
    }

    private async Task<IInputStream> GetContent(string path)
    {  
        try
        {
            Uri localUri = new Uri("ms-appx:///cloud-reader" + path);
            StorageFile f = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(localUri);
            IRandomAccessStream stream = await f.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
            return stream;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw new Exception("Invalid path");
        }
    }
}
```

¿De qué forma se haría lo mismo en Xamarin.Forms?
Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al final pude cargar la web de forma local utilizando un custom render para cada plataforma.

Ejemplo (UWP):

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(WebView), typeof(WebViewRenderer))]
namespace DisplayEpub.UWP{
public class CustomWebViewRenderer : WebViewRenderer
{
   protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<WebView> e)
   {
       base.OnElementChanged(e);

       if (e.NewElement != null)
       {
           var customWebView = Element as WebView;
           Control.Source = new Uri(string.Format("ms-appx-web:///Assets/pdfjs/web/viewer.html"));
       }
   }
}
}
```

He seguido el ejemplo de la documentación de Xamarin para mostrar PDF en el webview, en las 3 plataformas usando custom render. Lo he probado en Android y Windows: https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/controls/display-pdf/